# Docker update or build from new one

Tags: docker

I want to ask if I have an old version of docker image and I built a version of the same image does docker update new content only or rebuild the image from the beginning.

I tried locally and I noticed that it takes from the old image then update the new one. but I want to know if the same can be done on aws fargate

Comment: Are you asking generally, or on Fargate specifically? Docker will reuse intermediate images if it has them, but I doubt Fargate caches them for you.

Comment: I’m asking specifically about fargate

Comment: Per e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/51618252/3001761, it looks like there's no caching involved on Fargate.

Comment: @jonrsharpe okay thanks